# No resource identifier found for attribute 'isSelected' in package 'com.jbirdvegas.mgerrit'

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, compilation

I'm trying to build AOKP (jb-mr1) but i'm getting this errors :

packages/apps/ROMControl/../../../external/jbirdvegas/mGerrit/res/drawable/commit_card_background_states.xml:24: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'isSelected' in package 'com.jbirdvegas.mgerrit'
packages/apps/ROMControl/../../../external/jbirdvegas/mGerrit/res/drawable/commit_card_background_states_dark.xml:24: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'isSelected' in package 'com.jbirdvegas.mgerrit'

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jbirdvegas.mgerrit">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/card_pressed" />
    <item app:isSelected="true" android:drawable="@color/card_selected" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@color/card_background" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/card_background"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@color/main_background"/>
</selector>
```

The code seems fine but i'm getting these errors. If anyone can help, please, i'm stuck.

Comment: try to change xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jbirdvegas.mgerrit" to xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Hope no more errors.

Comment: @Rami What exactly does that do?